# What is the native Gnome equivalent for Kile?

Tags: gnome, software-rec, editors, latex

I was using Kile for editing Latex documents, but after latest package upgrade (I am running Debian Testing) all Kde applications are running reeeeaaaallllly slow - so I am looking for a temporary Gnome based (GTK) substitute.

I am looking for an application that will allow me to edit text, highlight syntax, have a button to run pdflatex (and ideally bibtex if needed, and then pdflatex again etc.), another button for viewing the latest pdf. Syntax and reference completion would be a bonus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not a dedicated GNOME latex editor, for what I know, apart from `gedit` + `gedit-latex-plugin`.

A gtk alternative could be `geany` + `geany-plugin-latex`.

Answer (score 1):

`emacs` + `auctex` + `preview`

Answer (score 1):

[Latexila](http://projects.gnome.org/latexila/) is a good IDE for gnome platform written in Vala. It offers features like autocompletion, a sidebar for symbols, syntax colouring and single click compile and build facility.

Answer (score 0):

I use [TexMaker](https://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/). is light and good!